# Injecting Variables into a Magento 2 CMS static block

Tags: magento2.2, static-block

**Magento 1 Way :-**

https://inchoo.net/magento/injecting-variables-into-a-magento-cms-static-block/

I need the same in Magento 2, how can I achieve? it's urgent.

**Here is my afford:-**

```
<?php

namespace Test\Clientform\Controller\Show;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_filterProvider;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_blockFactory;
    protected $_filterFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory $blockFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filter\Template $filterFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_filterProvider = $filterProvider;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_blockFactory = $blockFactory;
        $this->_filterFactory = $filterFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {


        $blockId = 'client_intake_form';
        $html = '';
        if ($blockId) {
            $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
            /** @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Block $block */
            $block = $this->_blockFactory->create();
            $block->setStoreId($storeId)->load($blockId);

            $array['full_name'] = 'test';

             $this->_filterFactory->setVariables($array);
             // exit;
             //exit;
                $html = $this->_filterProvider->getBlockFilter()->setStoreId($storeId)->filter($block->getContent());
        }
        echo   $html;

        // $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        // return $resultPage;
    }



}

?>
```

When I'm hitting controller:-

http://127.0.0.1/Magento2/test/show/index

still not able to set value.

**you can check here:-**

http://nimb.ws/TEZVRp

**To set value I've used  \Magento\Framework\Filter\Template $filterFactory,**

& calling setVariables() method.

When I'm setting values directly in the core class:-

\Magento\Framework\Filter\Template $filterFactory

**e.g-**

```
public function setVariables(array $variables)
    {
        $variables['full_name'] = 'test'; // added this line staticaly
        foreach ($variables as $name => $value) {
            $this->templateVars[$name] = $value;
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Then value gets set, you can check here:-

http://nimb.ws/ytvcRV

**so please let me know why I'm not able to set value from the controller.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created a sample code and its working fine for me:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$content = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory')->create();
$content->load('test_block', 'identifier'); // Load static block
$array['test'] = 'Test Block'; //Set variables
$filter = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter');
$filter->setVariables($array);
$html = $filter->filter($content->getContent());
return $html;
```

Stati block code for **test_block**:

```
<p>{{var test}}</p>
```

You need to manage to add this your function.

Comment: You welcome. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 3):

With the help of @Sukumar finally, I reach to the solution.

**Here it is:-**

```
<?php

namespace Test\Clientform\Controller\Show;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_filterProvider;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_blockFactory;
    protected $_filterTemplate;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory $blockFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filter\Template $filterTemplate,
       // \Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter $filterTemplate, // OR you can also use it
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_filterProvider = $filterProvider;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_blockFactory = $blockFactory;
        $this->_filterTemplate = $filterTemplate;
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $blockId = 'client_intake_form';
        $html = '';
        if ($blockId) {
            $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
            /** @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Block $block */
            $block = $this->_blockFactory->create();
            $block->setStoreId($storeId)->load($blockId);

            $array['full_name'] = 'test';

             $this->_filterTemplate->setVariables($array);

              $html = $this->_filterTemplate->filter($block->getContent());

        }
        echo   $html;


    }


}

?>
```